# Left join in sql

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

Below is my select query,

```
SELECT Persons.LastName, Persons.FirstName, Orders.OrderNo, Invoice.InvoiceNo
FROM Persons
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON Persons.Id_P=Orders.Id_P 
LEFT JOIN Invoice
ON Persons.Id_P=Invoice.Id_P
```

I want to get oderNo and InvoiceNo with left join to Table Persons. However, I can get OrderNo only. I can't get InvoiceNo.

Is It I can't use `Persons.Id_P` two time to join table orders and invoice? But then how I can solve this problem?

Anyone know please help me. Thank you very much!

The problem had solved dy. It's my human error at other part of sql. The above query is correct.Thank You.

Comment: The JOINs look good, can you show us some data examples?

Comment: Please add some output that you want to get.

Comment: Please enter table structers

Comment: This is just a sample sql I created. Mine one is too big. I just curious Persons.Id_P can't use two time to link two table??Is It correct?

Comment: Yes you can very well use and thus people commented saying query looks good.

Comment: I see, Then that's must my other part getting wrong dy. Thanks for answering me!

Comment: Try SQLFiddle. Add a test case there.

Comment: @Raptor I found the mistake dy. It's not about left join problem. It's just my human error. My select query above is correct. Anyway, thanks you for giving help

Comment: @eric glad you solved the problem yourself. (that's why I said the JOINs are okay)

Comment: @Raptor Yaya, If not I will continue stuck on left-join problem. Thanks again